# Don't get what is happening in matlab sin() function. need to know difference between sin(2*50*pi*t) and sin(2*1*pi*t)

Tags: matlab, wave-equation

I am using Matlab to plot the sin graph. But when I put sin(2*50*pi*t) it shows something else than the sinusoidal curve. Can you please help me to find out why it is happening? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
t = 0:0.1:20;
x = sin(2*50*pi*t);
y = sin(2*1*pi*t);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,y)
```

This picture is showing the output of both sin waves

[image: picture]

Comment: feels like machine precision issues with the first curve, values are too small

Comment: You need more sample points in the first plot.

Comment: I used t = 0:.01:200 and kind of same result I get. Here I am attaching you a graph for t = -20:0.01:20; https://imgur.com/a/nimTxNl

Comment: $\sin(50t)$ has period $\frac{\pi}{25}\approx 0.12,$ and your $t$ is based on increments of $0.1.$ So it will be hard to see the periodic behavior of $\sin(50t).$

Comment: If you only graphed $\sin(2), \sin(4),\sin(6),\dots$ (using radians, not degrees) your graph will seem similarly odd.

Comment: Better for Computational Science SE, in my opinion.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab+or+octave) with the MATLAB tag would probably be the most appropriate place for this question.